# Change System.Windows.Window size with a UserControl Content

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, resize, window

I got a UserControl that I display within a Window with the following code :

```
loadingWindow = new System.Windows.Window
{
    Title = "Loading",
    Content = new Loading(),
};
loadingWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Where Loading class is a UserControl. I can't find how resize the Window (it appears very huge on the screen).

Change the size of the UserControl is not working.

Any idea ? Thank's,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loadingWindow.Width` and `loadingWindow.Height`

or `.size`

Comment: Oh god, forgot the Width and Height attributes. Working perfectly ;) However, the .size does not exist. Thank you.